# Best resources for learning Machine Learning for beginners

Tags: machine-learning

I am keen in learning machining learning. I know programming, just want to know some useful sites which will help in understanding the concepts of machine learning with simple examples.

Comment: I suggest you to read about [FACE RECOGNITION](http://www.face-rec.org/) that's use machining learning concepts.

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner in Machine Learning you should start with the book

> Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, by Christopher M. Bishop

There are some prerequisites other than programming are Linear Algebra, Probability theory, etc. i.e. you should have a strong background in Mathematics. Although the book I suggested covers the common mathematical frameworks needed for understanding Machine Learning in its introductory chapters.

Moreover, you should practice implementing different learning algorithms (start from smaller ones) to grab the concepts well. As [Andrej Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/) said,

> ...everything became much clearer when I started writing code.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks. But what if I want to jump straight into code and learn the brief details "side-by-side", what would be the best option?